# Excepcion al leer cierta columna DataSet cargada con el contenido de un archivo XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

Tengo un archivo XML donde cargo sus datos en un DataSet

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/datos.xml"));
```

Al intentar leer la columna 'NumCodigo' de la forma:

```
ds.Tables["NumCodigo"].Rows[0]["NumCodigo"]
```

Tengo una excepción con el siguiente mensaje:

> La columna ‘NumCodigo’ no pertenece a la tabla NumCodigo.”

He cambiado el nombre de este elemento en el archivo XML por NCodigo y entonces si que me sale el valor correspondiente que seria 123456.

```
ds.Tables["NCodigo"].Rows[0]["NumCodigo"]
```

Pero necesito acceder por el nombre `NumCodigo`. Si accedo por índice también me sale el mismo error a no ser que le cambie el nombre también por `NCodigo`.

El archivo XML es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Productos>
    <P11>1</P11>
    <P12>1</P12>
    <P14>1</P14>
    <P21>0</P21>
  </Productos>
  <Cantidades>
    <Tipo>A</Tipo>
    <Producto>P11</Producto>
    <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
  </Cantidades>
  <Cantidades>
    <Tipo>B</Tipo>
    <Producto>P12</Producto>
    <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
  </Cantidades>
  <Cantidades>
    <Tipo>C</Tipo>
    <Producto>P14</Producto>
    <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
  </Cantidades>
  <NumCodigo>
    <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
  </NumCodigo>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Bueno, estoy haciendo varias pruebas y el problema evidentemente es que la tabla se llama igual que el campo. Si en tu xml cambias el nombre de la tabla de `NumCodigo` a `NumCodigos`, funciona correctamente. Parece que a `ReadXml` no le gusta que coincidan el nombre del padre y del hijo en el esquema xml.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Échale un vistazo a ver si te ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras realizar unas pruebas, parece que `DataSet.ReadXml` no es capaz de inferir correctamente el esquema de los datos si hay un campo cuyo nombre coincide con el nombre del elemento superior. Probablemente es algo inherente a la implementación interna del método y a la manera de recorrer los nodos para inferir el esquema de los datos.

Visto esto, tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar el nombre de la tabla para que no coincida con el de la columna:

   ```
   ...
   <NumCodigos>
      <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
   </NumCodigos>
   ```
2. Incluir el esquema de los datos en tu archivo xml. Te pongo como quedaría en tu ejemplo:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
   <NewDataSet>
     <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
       <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xs:element name="Productos">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="P11" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                   <xs:element name="P12" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                   <xs:element name="P14" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                   <xs:element name="P21" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="Cantidades">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="Tipo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                   <xs:element name="Producto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                   <xs:element name="NumCodigo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="NumCodigo">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="NumCodigo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:choice>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
     </xs:schema>
     <Productos>
       <P11>1</P11>
       <P12>1</P12>
       <P14>1</P14>
       <P21>0</P21>
     </Productos>
     <Cantidades>
       <Tipo>A</Tipo>
       <Producto>P11</Producto>
       <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
     </Cantidades>
     <Cantidades>
       <Tipo>B</Tipo>
       <Producto>P12</Producto>
       <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
     </Cantidades>
     <Cantidades>
       <Tipo>C</Tipo>
       <Producto>P14</Producto>
       <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
     </Cantidades>
     <NumCodigo>
       <NumCodigo>123456</NumCodigo>
     </NumCodigo>
   </NewDataSet>
   ```

Si el archivo xml con los datos lo estás generando tu usando `DataSet.WriteXml`, lo que debes hacer es añadir el parámetro `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` para que añada el esquema al archivo:

```cs
ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/datos.xml"),XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

**Editado**

Hay una tercera opción, que puedes usar si (como parece que es tu caso) no tienes acceso a modificar el archivo xml. Esta opción es generar el esquema de datos en tu `DataSet` antes de importarlo. Voy a usar el ejemplo que has puesto:

```cs
//Creamos las tablas y campos necesarios:

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Productos");
dt1.Columns.Add("P11", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("P12", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("P14", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("P21", typeof(int));

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Cantidades");
dt2.Columns.Add("Tipo");
dt2.Columns.Add("Producto");
dt2.Columns.Add("NumCodigo", typeof(int));

DataTable dt3 = new DataTable("NumCodigo");
dt3.Columns.Add("NumCodigo");

//Añadimos las tablas a un nuevo DataSet
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
ds.Tables.Add(dt3);

//Ahora en ds ya tenemos el esquema de datos correcto. Ya podemos importar los datos

ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/datos.xml"));
var col = ds.Tables["NumCodigo"].Rows[0]["NumCodigo"];
```

Usando este método debes tener en cuenta que las tablas y campos que generas deben coincidir con el esquema de los datos del xml, y si este varía debes modificarlo en tu código también.

**Edición 2**

Creo que la manera óptima de resolver el problema en tu caso es tener el esquema en un archivo xsd, y leerlo antes de importar los datos. Resumiendo:

- Creas un archivo `datos.xsd` con el esquema:

  ```
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Productos">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="P11" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="P12" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="P14" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="P21" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Cantidades">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Tipo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Producto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="NumCodigo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="NumCodigo">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="NumCodigo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  ```
- Ahora, hacemos uso del método `ReadXmlSchema` para primero leer el esquema y luego importar los datos:

  ```cs
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  //leemos el esquema
  ds.ReadXmlSchema(Server.MapPath("~/datos.xsd"));
  //importamos los datos
  ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/datos.xml"));
  //accedemos a la columna
  var col = ds1.Tables["NumCodigo"].Rows[0]["NumCodigo"];
  ```

Comment: Cuando añado el _id me muestra un 0 si en Rows tengo índice 0. Si en Rows pongo índice 1 me muestra un 1. No me muestra el numero 123456.  Es rarísimo no lo entiendo. ¿Alomejor tengo que leer el archivo XML con ReadXML añadiendo algún parámetro ?

Comment: El archivo lo genera un WebService entonces no se como añadir el schema.

Comment: ¿ Quizas alomejor hay alguna librería externa que pueda añadir a ASP que me lea el XML bien ? ¿ O pasar el XML a JSON con algún metodo de ASP y coger los datos desde un JSON?

Comment: ¿Se puede añadir el XML a una variable y desde allí añadir el schema para luego pasárselo al DataSet?

Comment: No, el webService no se puede tocar.

Comment: @Popularfan mira la respuesta editada a ver si se adapta a tus necesidades

Comment: La de añadir el XML a una variable string y luego el esquema creo que seria lo mas correcto ya que si luego el webservice añade algún atributo mas seria mas fácil implementarlo. Seria la Cuarta solución. ¿ Te resultaría fácil añadir esta solución también ?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: @Popularfan mira mi segunda edición. Creo que es exactamente lo que necesitas en tu caso :)

Comment: ¿ Quieres decir que genere el xsd manualmente en un archivo ? ¿Como genero el .xsd ?

Comment: @Popularfan no tienes que hacerlo manualmente. Simplemente usa la utilidad [`xsd.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) que viene con visual studio. Solo tienes que ejecutar `xsd archivo.xml` en un ejemplo de archivo `xml` y te genera automáticamente un archivo `xsd`

Comment: Ok, pensaba que habia un metodo que lo generaba por codigo en ese caso tendre que llamar al .exe desde codigo. Ahora lo pruebo

Comment: @Popularfan no creo que sea necesario hacerlo desde el código. el proceso de crear un `.xsd` solo debes hacerlo uno vez, o cuando se modifique el esquema. Simplemente generalo una vez usando un xml de ejemplo, y guarda ese archivo xsd para leerlo posteriormente

Comment: Ok !!! Funciona !!! Lo probé haciendo un xsd desde una pagina que lo genera online ya que las tools con el xsd.exe no lo tenia instalado. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo me ha sido de gran ayuda !

Comment: Si, hay varias herramientas online para generar xsd. Me alegro de que te funcione correctamente @Popularfan :)